# ADB does not recognize my Panasoinc T21 android smartphone even after installing the "android_winusb.inf" driver

Tags: android, adb

I was trying to connect my Panasonic T21 android smart phone through ADB but inspite of all my effort, I am unable to connect it. What I did so far is

1. Downloaded the Google-USB driver using SDK Manager.
2. Modified the "android_winusb.inf" file and included the hardware ids
   of panasonic device. Included the below code under [Google.NTx86]
   and [Google.NTamd64] and saved the file.

   ***;Panasonic %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0A5C&PID_E688 %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install,
   USB\VID_0A5C&PID_E688&REV_0231&MI_01***
3. Installed the driver through, My Computer->Device Manager.
4. Now I could see "Android Composite ADB Interface" under "Android
   Phone" in Device Manager.
5. However on giving the adb devices command from command prompt,there
   is no devices displayed under "List of devices attached"

I have restarted ADB,my Win7 PC, and the device as well but the problem still persist. I am desperately looking for a solution. Please help me.

Comment: did you enable usb debugging on your phone?

Comment: Yes i have enabled the "USB Debugging" and tried connected my phone as a media device and as camera. Still no luck..

Answer (score 1):

After step 2, 
first,disable driver signature enforcement (advanced startup options).
Second,install the driver - go to device manager-->select your device --> update the driver manually

You can refer to this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPm_6aejOlo#t=55

Comment: Hi Erasmas,Thanks for your reply. I have a query here, we need to disable driver signature enforcement if we are facing issues while installing drivder. However my issue is not pertaining to installation. I am able to install the driver and now I could see "Android Composite ADB Interface" under "Android Phone" in Device Manager.But on giving the adb devices command from command prompt,there is no devices displayed under "List of devices attached".

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly. On 64 bit systems systems unsigned drivers are not allowed unless one disables driver verification at boot.

For windows 7 press f8 at boot and choose disable driver verification. For Windows 8 follow the steps in the video above.

After that its very easy to root with cydiaimpactor. Infact cydiaimpactor can itself install the driver for you.

On 32bit systems this is not a problem and windows does not enforce driver verification and signing.

See this link https://www.raymond.cc/blog/loading-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-7-and-vista-64-bit-x64/